# How to call JavaScript on elements loaded with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some functionality that I want to work when the document is ready and also after Ajax is called, as new items are loaded into the page that need to be selected.

I can accomplish this by doing this:

```
var ready;
ready = function(){
  //my code here
};

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).ajaxComplete(ready)
```

But that causes an issue where each Ajax call seems to add another time for the function to run. After the first AjaxComplete call, it runs once, then twice, then three times, etc.

How do I elegantly get all the code to run how I want it just once at any point while the user is on the page?

It is a Ruby on Rails app, btw.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The magic word is event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for jQuery's `.delegate` function. What is does is it binds to a parent element, and whenever an event is fired inside of it, it checks to see if the child element producing the event matches the selector you provided; if it does, it'll fire the handler. For instance the folowing example from [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) causes a click on all existing and future `td`s within a table to toggle the "chosen" class:

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

So if you add a new row to a table, clicking on it will toggle "chosen" even though the row didn't exist when you called delegate.

Let me know if this makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Not exactly, it binds it to only one element, the table. When the event propagates to the table, jQuery tests to see if the `event.target` matches the given selector (`"td"`) and if it does, runs the callback with `this` equal to `event.target`.

Comment: This worked perfectly in the use case. I'll leave it open for a bit to see if there are any other solutions that would apply in a more general sense, rather than changing all the functions. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @KevinB I meant that it effectively binds more so than literally, but updated the answer to reflect the inner workings. Does it seem better now? (Feel free to edit it if there's anything you wish to add)

Comment: Yes, that's much better. :)